# stub of .save() returns nothing and times out

Tags: node.js, testing, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I need to assert return of naturalController.add() with the fixture.

I have the function add in my controller in promise, and in my model has a .pre() (which seems to me the origin of the problem) that is called before the .save() I have no idea what is happens, someone can help me?

What the test does:

1. Instantiates a controller loading the default model.
2. Calls the `.add()` method with a promise with valid data(it passes ajv which I omitted).
3. The class instantiates a new document (I think the problem is around here).
4. The class calls the `.save()` method of the document instance(everything stops here and I get a time out at mocha).

At another test everything works fine. I can add as many documents as I wish through postman and integration tests.

Testing:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';
import NaturalPersonModel from './../../../src/models/naturalPersonModel';
import naturalPersonFixture from '../../fixtures/naturalPersonFixture';

describe('NaturalController', function() {
      var stubSave,
        naturalController = new NaturalController();

      context('#add', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
          stubSave = sinon.stub(NaturalPersonModel.prototype, "save");
        });

        afterEach(function() {
          stubSave.restore();
        });

        it('resolve when data is ok', function() {
          stubSave.returns(Bluebird.resolve(naturalPersonFixture.save));
          return naturalController.add(naturalPersonFixture.add)
            .then(function(value) {
              chai.assert(value === naturalPersonFixture.save);
            });
        });
      });
    });
```

class code:

```
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';
import NaturalPerson from './../models/naturalPersonModel';

class NaturalController {
  constructor() {
    this.naturalPersonModel = NaturalPerson;
  }

      add(data) {
            var newNP = new this.naturalPersonModel(data);
            return newNP.save()
            .catch(function(reason){
              throw new Error(reason);
            });
      }
    }
export default NaturalController;
```

model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
import Bluebird from 'bluebird';
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection);

var naturalPersonSchemaBr = new mongoose.Schema({
  naturalPersonData:{
    personUUID: String,
    nome: {type: String,required:true},
    sobrenome: {type: String,required:true},
    cpf: {type: String,required:true,unique:true},
    rg: {type: String,required:true},
    purchase:{
      firstBuyStoreUUID: Number,
      firstSellerUUID: Number
    }
  }
});
naturalPersonSchemaBr.methods.capitalizeFn = function(obj, list) {
   String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
     return this.split(' ').map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join(' ');
   };
   list.forEach((attr) => {
     if (obj[attr] && typeof(obj[attr]) === 'string') {
       obj[attr] = obj[attr].toLowerCase().capitalize();
     }
   });
 };

 naturalPersonSchemaBr.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
   model: 'NaturalPerson',
   field: 'UUIDcounter',
   startAt: 1,
   incrementBy: 1
 });

naturalPersonSchemaBr.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  user.naturalPersonData.personUUID = "NP"+ user.UUIDcounter;
  console.log("user",user);
  var list = ['nome','sobrenome','cpf','rg'];
  naturalPersonSchemaBr.methods.capitalizeFn(user.naturalPersonData,list);
  return next();
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('NaturalPerson', naturalPersonSchemaBr);
```

Comment: The model's instance .save() times out. It is inside a class. As it does not return anything (it was suposed to be stubed), mocha keeps waiting and finally times out. I just edited the question

Comment: two things `naturalController = new NaturalController();` move this in before each - after the `.stub` line and `stubSave.returns(Bluebird.resolve(naturalPersonFixture.save));` this is not making sense, you should return empty object in resolve if you dont have anything to return `Bluebird.resolve({})`

Comment: I tried both, none worked. I think that `Bluebird.resolve({})` is not correct because i want to assert something to be sure newNP.save() was called. One thing i did not mention: the integretion tests and postman calls to the route DO work. I just can't do the unit test. There seems to be a problem with inheritance, because documents methods like .get (e.g:newNP.get('name')) do work with this unit test code.

Comment: @Louis regarding the timeout, this is actually an async test, as he returns a Promise in the test, which mocha treats as a special case.

Comment: There are so many strange things about the code in the test and the actual code, but there is at least one simplification you can do, and that is to use the built in promise support in Sinon 2.3, using `stub.resolves()`: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.5/stubs/

So change the stub.returns(Bluebird.resolve()) bit to read `stub.resolves()`.

Comment: @oligofren The question was edited after I commented. The original code was as I described in my earlier comment (definitely did not return *anything*). I've deleted my original comment now but this question still needs a [mcve].

Comment: I changed the question again trying to make it more [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @oligofren even with `stub.resolves(object)` instead of `stub.returns(Bluebird.resolve(object))` i get nothing.

Comment: As you can see from my answer, your test is fine. There must be something else going on. I would try updating for instance sinon to the latest version. As in `npm i sinon@latest`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must be doing something wrong, because your test seems to work :-) The test code had some errors, making it not immediately runnable, such as the fixture code being missing, but I just replaced the `import naturalPersonFixture ..` with a constant, seeing that it was just an object from the context.

I uploaded all the files as a gist for [easy download and playing with](https://gist.github.com/d848fc9b8e90a1df32c706488580b9ff). The example was far from minimal, but I still got it working by doing this:

1. Install Mongo
2. Run `mongod --dbpath /tmp/testdb`
3. `npm i mongoose mongoose-auto-increment mocha chai-as-promised sinon bluebird  babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread babel-cli babel-eslint babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx babel-preset-es2015 babel-root-slash-import`
4. Set up babel (see gist link)
5. Run the test: `mocha --compilers js:babel-register -s 4 test.js`

Not exactly minimal! But it worked :D

```
$  mocha --compilers js:babel-register  test.js


  NaturalController
    #add
      ✓ resolve when data is ok (5ms)


  1 passing (78ms)
```

Comment: ok.. adding your code(include packge's) to my code is not working, but it works in a new project. I will try to find the problem, thanks for the help, i will post what i find when i solve it.

Comment: @ThiagoFreitas When something inexplicable like that happens, one usual culprit is node_modules. Try deleting that folder and reinstalling everything.

Comment: I deleted and installed again, it finally worked out. I do not have the slightest idea of what was the problem. Thank you very much the problem was solved

Comment: i can only accept, still i'm not allowed to upvote because i need 15 of reputation, i will do it once i'm allowed.